Laravel: Cannot instantiate interface Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher
I have a website built with Laravel 11. The website runs smoothly, but sometimes it gets an error like 500 server error. I checked the laravel.log and found this.
local.ERROR: Cannot instantiate interface Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher.

This error will resolve itself and will eventually happen again. I noticed that it could happen if my website traffic has a lot of requests, like up to 50 requests at that time (the website analytics is per 10 minutes).
Any suggestion to solve this problem?

You should check the stack trace of the error and see where the interface is being initiated. In some places, you should have an event dispatcher where the wrong class is being used.
